# How to access credentials passed in the authentication popup for a 401 response

Tags: playframework-2.0, authorization, unauthorized

I need to implement ActiveDirectory based authentication on my site I am developin gusing Play framework. As a demo, I created a sample app

```
public static Result index() 
{
    boolean IsLoggedIn = false;
    String authorization = request().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

    if(!IsLoggedIn)
    {
        String usrnm = request().username();
        response().setHeader(WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Enter Your ID and password\"");    
        return unauthorized("You Need to Login first");
    }
    return ok("Welcome to nowhere");
}
```

This opens a authentication popup on the client. Now, how do I access these credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer

```
 String authorization = request().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
```

The authorization header contains the username:password in a base64 encoded form.

```
AUTHORIZATION = "Basic oa76dfexvdd3=="
```

here, if you decode `oa76dfexvdd3==`, you will get something like "myusr:mypwd", which you can then use for the authentication.